# Initialising an associative array of struct values and string keys

Tags: initialization, d, associative-array

(for the "D" programming language)

I've been struggling trying to initialise an associative array that has struct elements and should be index-able by a string. I would import it as a module from a separate file.

This is what I want to achieve (and it doesn't work --- I don't know if this is even possible):

```
mnemonic_info[string] mnemonic_table = [
        /* name,         format,          opcode */
        "ADD": {mnemonic_format.Format3M, 0x18},
        ...

        /* NOTE: mnemonic_format is an enum type. */
        /* mnemonic_info is a struct with a mnemonic_format and an ubyte */
];
```

Note that this works fine for arrays indexable by integers.

Optimally, I would like this to be evaluated at compile-time, as I won't be changing it. However, if it's not possible, I would be glad if you told me of the best way to build such an array at/before immediate run-time.

I need this because I'm writing an assembler.

I have searched SO and the internets for an answer, but could only find examples with integers, and other things I didn't understand or couldn't make to work.

I really like D so far but it seems hard to learn due to there not being many tutorials online.

Thanks!

On a side note: is it possible to use Tuples for associative array elements instead of a custom struct?

**Edit**

There is one way I found so far, but it's pretty ugly:

```
mnemonic_info[string] mnemonic_table;
static this() { // Not idea what this does.
        mnemonic_info entry;

        entry.format = mnemonic_format.Format3M;
        entry.opcode = 0x18;
        mnemonic_table["ADD"] = entry;

        /* ... for all entries. */
}
```

Comment: What error the compiler gives you ?  
I don't see any error in your code, according to : http://www.d-programming-language.org/hash-map.html

Comment: I get different errors depending on where I put this. Currently, by putting it in the toplevel of the .d file, I get "Error: not an associative array initializer". I suppose this means the syntax is off? When I Google for the error, there are no hits. The d site also does not list special syntax for associative array initialisers. I'm confused.

Comment: Have you tried to initialize it in several statements ?
mnemonic_info[string] mnemonic_table;
mnemonic_table["ADD"]={ mnemonic_format.Format3M, 0x18 };

Comment: Then I get "no identifier for declarator mnemonic_table["ADD"]", using exactly your code. Note: this is only the first line of the errors, all the mnemonics get mentioned.

Comment: I've edited my question post to show one way that works --- but I really hoped for a nicer syntax. I hope someone will post a different solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In D, built-in associative array literals are always created in runtime, so initializing a global associative array by assigning it some value at declaration place is currently impossible.

As you found yourself, you can workaround that by assigning a value to associative array in [module constructor](http://www.d-programming-language.org/class.html#StaticConstructor).

The other problem in your code is struct initialization literals. You should prefer [D-style](http://www.d-programming-language.org/struct.html#StructLiteral) struct initializers to C-style ones.

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    string b;
}

Foo[string] global;

static this() {
    global = [
        "foo" : Foo(1, "hurr"),
        "bar" : Foo(2, "durr")
    ];
}

void main() {
    assert(global["foo"].a == 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Wasn't aware of D-style struct initialisers. I've read lots of pages about this today, and haven't seen it anywhere. Also, what about the `Foo(a:1, b:"hurr")` syntax? Doesn't seem to work, but is mentioned everywhere. :/

Comment: specifying which struct member you are initializing is restricted to C-style struct initializers. You might want to file an enhancement request to allow them in D-style initializers

Comment: When I try to use C-style initializers, they don't even work. :/
I only have 2 members, so it's not that important, but still.